# Extract values from same csv file based on column value

Tags: python, csv

I have this csv file:
1st field is entry or exit, Second is Id and third is time. So in short, entry and exit time based on Id.
I want to extract the first entry and first exit of same id and then minus the exit time from entry time. Like in this case, I want first row which is
"Entry, 25, 10.05" and "Exit, 25, 25.25"
Output I want is "25,15.20"

```
Entry,25, 10.05
Entry,25, 15.25
Entry,25, 20.25
Exit, 25, 25.25
Entry, 35, 30.20
Entry, 35, 70.25
Exit, 35, 80.20
Exit, 35, 90.20
```

I searched for any related post. Can someone refer me to the same post or answer this.

I got this code from one post, but I want little change, like how to deal with duplicate entries of the same id and how to subtract the exit time from entry time?

```
with open('datapipe.csv') as f:
  next(f) #- If header needs to be skipped.
  for line in f:
     en, id, value = line.rsplit(',', maxsplit=2)
     d[id] = d.get(id, 0) + float(value)

for k, v in d.items():
print(f"{k}, {v}")`
```

Comment: That is a very odd csv file format.  Frankly I would not even call it a csv file.  Where did you get it?

Comment: Format got changed while posting. Thanks for response.

Comment: _how to deal with duplicate entries of the same id_ Well, how do you **want** to handle it?  What **should** happen?  One way to handle it would be to ignore any duplicate ids after the first one.  Is that the right way for you?  We don't know.

Comment: I want first entry time and first exit time of the same id and subtract it. I hope now it is clear!! Thanks.